# Does Apple's Magic Trackpad Function When Using Windows 7 or 8 Via Boot Camp or Virtulization Software work?

Tags: windows-7, macos, windows-8, virtualization, magic-trackpad

Does the Magic Trackpad (and I guess the Magic Mouse) “work its magic”, function, gesture... when using Windows 7 or 8 either in Boot Camp or in VmWare Fusion /Parallels etc, or is Gesture Control confined to the Mac Operating System, as Gesture Control is not a part of Windows but is inherent to Mac OS X 10.6 > Snow Leopard, Lion & Mountain Lion ?

Comment: It will function if you provide the drivers to it.

Comment: @Ramhound - Is this something you have done, or know in theory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Magic" and "Gestures" are too subjective to comment on. However, gestures such as two-finger-scroll, tap-to-click, bottom-right-click do work. I have tried this with Windows 8 on MacBook Air. You have an option to select the settings you want in the Boot Camp Control Panel.

There may be other 3rd party drivers such as [Synaptics Gesture Suite](http://www.synaptics.com/solutions/technology/windows8) that let you configure other gestures.

Comment: Interesting. Thx for that. I have come across this article if it can be translated into English maybe very useful http://ariel4ever.wordpress.com/2012/11/25/mengaktifkan-apple-multi-trackpad-pada-windows-8/

Comment: Use Google Chrome - you will then be prompted to use Google Translate the page to English.

Comment: OK Thx i'll try it out !